# Converting string to Array (Aggregate mongodb)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Im getting random data from my database using the aggregate but apparently some of them have their genre values in string not in array, How can i convert those random data genre from string to array?

```
const book = await Book.aggregate([
       /* This is just for testing which books has genres in specific type
       { 
        $match: { genre: { $type: "string" } } 
       },
       */
 
      {   
        $sample: { size: 6 } 
      }
]);
```

sample data result(genres that are in type of string)

```
[
    {
        "_id": "62710ac63ad1bfc6d17030fe",
        "title": "Birth of a Theorem",
        "author": "Villani, Cedric",
        "genre": "mathematics",
        "publisher": "Bodley Head",
        "dateOfPublication": "2002-02-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "noOfCopies": 16,
        "type": "Book",
        "form": "Non-fiction",
        "isbn": "979-81202-479229-867673-6",
        "dateAdded": "2002-11-28T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "62710ac63ad1bfc6d1703108",
        "title": "All the President's Men",
        "author": "Woodward, Bob",
        "genre": "history",
        "publisher": "Random House",
        "dateOfPublication": "2018-02-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "noOfCopies": 56,
        "type": "Book",
        "form": "Non-fiction",
        "isbn": "978-41428-6606587-937631-",
        "dateAdded": "2011-02-23T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
]
```

sample data result(genres that are in type of array)

```
[
    {
        "_id": "62710ac63ad1bfc6d17030be",
        "title": "Superfreakonomics",
        "author": "Dubner, Stephen",
        "genre": [
            "economics",
            "computer_science"
        ],
        "publisher": "HarperCollins",
        "dateOfPublication": "2003-10-06T00:00:00.000Z",
        "noOfCopies": 31,
        "type": "Thesis",
        "form": "Non-fiction",
        "isbn": "978-35029-7186192-465859-7",
        "dateAdded": "2009-02-12T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$sample` is for documents instead of embedded array.

**Update**

```
db.collection.update({
  genre: {
    $type: "string"
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: { genre: [ "$genre" ] }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LimRzC8y6Yc)

---

**Aggregate**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      genre: {
        $type: "string"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      genre: {
        $cond: {
          if: { $eq: [ { $type: "$genre" }, "string" ] },
          then: [ "$genre" ],
          else: "$genre"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5FkbtcPdwnZ)

Comment: Hello, I tried using the update method but i dont know where to put it because im using asynchandler when getting the random data from db, but the aggregate method that you put in your answer worked for me. Thank you!